# Accessing SQLite PRAGMA User_version in Delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe, dbexpress

How do I access the result of

```
PRAGMA User_version
```

in Delphi using DbExpress components?

My code thus far:

```
SQL_dataset1.CommandType:=ctQuery;
SQL_dataset1.CommandText:='PRAGMA User_version';
SQL_dataset1.Open;

If SQL_dataset1.IsEmpty=False then
begin
  SQL_dataset1.First;

  Result:=SQL_dataset1.FieldByName('User_version').AsInteger;
  ........
```

... gives an error telling me that no field called User_version exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `SQL_dataset1.Fields[0].FieldName`?

Comment: Duh thanks, it's called 'Column0'! Got confused because in the SQLite browser the column header was 'User_version'.

Comment: I wonder why your DB driver does not read the column name. Try adding `/*SELECT*/` at the front of the SQL.